# Downloading PDF file - file path stored in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a download link for a PDF or docx files where a file path stored in MySQL DB.

My code below creates a variable called `$download` to capture the file path stored on the database and put in the download link shown in the table.

The download seems to work but when I download it but I did not get the pdf file that it is supposed to be download (store/5b8a579c0ee713.35728840.pdf).

PHP Code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $download = $row['inf_attachement']; //store/5b8a579c0ee713.35728840.pdf
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href=Infrastructureinfor.php?infid=" . $row['inf_id'] . ">" .  $row['inf_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['inf_Name'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['typ_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['island_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['inf_lat']. " ". $row['inf_long']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['inf_cmplt_Date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['inf_lifespan'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><a href="$download" download="report"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
endwhile;    
$result->close();
```

Comment: Did any errors occur?

Comment: what you expect and what you get?

Comment: _“but when I download it, it is not what I expect”_ - and that is not the kind of problem description we expect here - please go read [ask]! -- You neglected to close the first link at the start of your table row here, maybe that’s already it.

Comment: There are no errors occur when I clicked on the download link, I was able to download a file but it is not a pdf or docx file saved. This is what I get : report Failed - No file
http://localhost/PHP/$download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not echoing the variable but a string in this line:

```
 echo '<td><a href="$download" download="report"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></td>';
```

this is because of a misuse of the quotes.you can do:

```
 echo '<td><a href="'.$download.'" download="report"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></td>';
```

with single quotes you have to concatenate the variable to be echoed
or you can do:

```
 echo "<td><a href=\"$download\" download=\"report\"><i class=\"fa fa-download\"></i></a></td>";
```

if you use double quotes you have to escape those that are internal to the string and the variable will be parsed without any problem